# Unable to access folders in same level as wordpress installation

Tags: redirect, htaccess, errors, directory

I've got the following structure

```
www/
  .htaccess
  /website1
  /website2
  /uploads/foo.pdf
  /websiteWP
    .htaccess
```

`.htacces` in root (www/.htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?foo.com$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/websiteWP/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /websiteWP/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?foo.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ websiteWP/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

`.htacces` in wordpress installation (www/websiteWP/.htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Inside the Wordpress, clicking the link https://www.foo.com/uploads/some-pdf.pdf will result in an infinite loading page, trying to load content (this reaction is due to the theme, I supose others can have a 404), or sometimes combining half wordpress with half "embeded" remote page.

But going to the pdf from outside the website (pasting in the search box) will work.

> **Note:**
>
> Wordpress URL: https://www.foo.com/websiteWP
>
> Website URL: https://www.foo.com

Can't find the failure of the `.htaccess`.

Already checked all available threads in stackoverflow and wordpress stackexchange.

Comment: In your example link you've used `foo.es`, but in other places you've used `foo.com` - is that intentional? Or should it all be `foo.com`? Do you have multiple domains? "But going to the pdf from outside the website will work" - there should be no difference - if the link is the same then the result should be the same, since they both result in the same request.

Comment: @MrWhite mb doing the dummy data, all is foo.com

Comment: @MrWhite one is a link inside wordpess clicked through the website, the other one is an external link. But yes, basically the same request.

Comment: ...but with a different _result_?

Comment: Yes, I started to think that is more likely to be a theme problem than a missconfirugation. I think there is javascript that make transitions between page and page that provoque the page to not load a page and it tries to load the pdf/external website inside the content of the current site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from the `.htaccess` files you've posted why you can't access files/folders outside of your WordPress installation (inside the `/websiteWP` subdirectory). In fact, you shouldn't need to add specific exceptions in order to access physical files, since these directives shouldn't apply to physical files.

However, your `.htaccess` files are misconfigured...

If the WordPress installation is in `/websiteWP` directory then the `/websiteWP/.htaccess` file (in the route of your WordPress installation) is incorrect, as it is routing all requests to `/index.php` - that's the `index.php` file in the document root (which I assume is the parent directory), not the WordPress front-controller which should be in the same directory, ie. `/websiteWP/index.php`).

However, I assume `/index.php` (in the document root) doesn't exist (otherwise your WordPress site won't work). The `.htaccess` directives in the root `.htaccess` file are then rewriting the request back to the `/websiteWP/index.php` WordPress front-controller! This is extra work and unnecessary.

You should change the `/websiteWP/.htaccess` file to read:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note I have removed the `RewriteBase` directive and removed the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *susbstitution*, changing `/index.php` (root-relative) to `index.php` (relative).

Then, the root `.htaccess` file is not required at all.

Comment: I'll try this solution, wordpress's guide says to put a htaccess in root folder [guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Method_I_.28Without_URL_change.29), that make sense cause I need to redirect / to /new/ otherwise a forbidden access will apear since root folder has no index.php

But maybe root's htaccess has redundant information.

Comment: Sometimes I got an **Cannot parse upstream response** error when I visit a page in wordpress (https://www.foo.com/some-page/) [image](https://imgur.com/a/VYmDlj0)

Comment: That "guide" is regarding _moving_ an installation that was in the root to a subdirectory, without necessarily changing the URL (ie. without exposing the subdirectory). Or having an installation in a subdirectory, but making it look as if it is in the root? Is that what you have done? However, you would still need to modify the subdirectory `.htaccess` file to avoid this "double" rewrite. The root `.htaccess` file doesn't actually "redirect" anything, it "rewrites" the URL. Maybe you do need a "redirect"? Should `/websiteWP` be part of the URL?

Comment: As it stands it looks like your WordPress pages maybe accessible from 2 URLs, both with and without the `/websiteWP` subdirectory. I'm not sure what "Cannot parse upstream response" would relate to? You say you only get that error "sometimes"?

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm confusing you even more. **having an installation in a subdirectory, but making it look as if it is in the root** that's it. There is no website on root, all websites are in their folders, but wanted to make /websiteWP/ the main one, without showing the folder.

Comment: I removed theme's transition between pages, and now pdfs and other websites in folders are accessible without problems. I apreciate your correction of the /websiteWP/ htaccess :)